# find min and max value using reduce es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

If I have array of object like this

```
[{min:5,max:10,id:1}, {min:50,max:3,id:2}, {min:1,max:40,id:3}]
```

How to find min and max using reduce? I know I can use generic loop and compare but I would like to explore reduce in es2015

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for; what would the correct answer for the min be for the above, for example?  The ID of the item with the lowest min value, i.e. 3?

Comment: `reduce` in ES6 isn't different from `reduce` in ES5.

Comment: `reduce` *is* a generic loop, where all state is passed on through the accumulator.

Comment: @Bergi I'm using the wrong function here?

Comment: The function is right, it's just not ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reduce like this to get the min and max numbers from each object in the array.

```js
const arr = [{min:5,max:10,id:1}, {min:50,max:3,id:2}, {min:1,max:40,id:3}]

console.log(
  arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc.min = Math.min(acc.min, x.min)
    acc.max = Math.max(acc.max, x.max)
    return acc
  }, { min: Infinity, max: -Infinity })
)

// as Bergi suggested, we could just return a new Object literal
// from the reduction
console.log(
  arr.reduce((acc, x) => ({
    min: Math.min(acc.min, x.min),
    max: Math.max(acc.max, x.max)
  }), { min: Infinity, max: -Infinity })
)
```

Comment: Maybe even avoid the mutation of `acc` and just return a new object literal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{min:5,max:10,id:1}, {min:50,max:3,id:2}, {min:1,max:40,id:3}];

const min = arr.reduce((m, o) => m < o.min? m: o.min, +Infinity),
      max = arr.reduce((M, o) => M > o.max? M: o.max, -Infinity);

console.log("Min:", min);
console.log("Max:", max);
```

**Explanation of min:**

```
const min = arr.reduce((m, o) => { // for each object o in the array arr
    return m < o.min?              // if o.min is bigger than the minimum m
              m:                   // then the minimum is still m
              o.min;               // otherwise, the new minimum is o.min
}, +Infinity);                     // pass in +Ifinity as the minimum (the initial value of m so whatever is arr[0].min is it will be smaller than m). You can pass in arr[0].min if you want instead of +Infinity
```

Comment: @AlanJenshen Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want, for the minimum, to get the id of the item with the lowed `min` value, then this will do it.

```
const items = [{min:5,max:10,id:1}, {min:50,max:3,id:2}, {min:1,max:40,id:3}];

// Reduce to find the item with the lowest min
const min = items.reduce((res, item) => {
  // No result yet, so the item must be the lowest seen
  if (!res) return item;
  // Use the lowest of the current lowest and the current item
  return item.min < res.min ? item : res;
}, undefined).id;
```

Comment: Hmm item is index here?

Comment: how to not use return here? I know you can use `(` instead of `{`

Comment: No.  Item is the entire object, e.g. `{min:5,max:10,id:1}`.  `res` is whatever you return, `item` is each item in the array.

Comment: You can only use `()`, which does an implicit return, if your function is a single statement.  You could do that here with a nested ternary, but I wouldn't because it would be less readable.

Comment: I guess you could also pass in a dummy initial object (I'm passing in `undefined`) which would allow you to skip the `if (!res)` check; it would end up looking similar to ibrahim's version above then.  The main difference is that my version returns the whole object rather than just the found min/max value - I assume that's what you need because otherwise there's not much point to the `id` value on each of your items...