# How do I solve this with .reduce() only?

Tags: javascript

Here's a simple task: Find the minimum of an array. Example array: `[ -52, 56, 30, 29, -54, 0, -110 ]`. I'm trying to solve this with the 'reduce()' higher-order function, WITHOUT using Math.min() or any sorting algorithms/functions. So far I've got this code, x is doing fine and having the right values, but the final iteration returns a weird version of the input array, instead of the minimum:

```js
const input = [-52, 56, 30, 29, -54, 0, -110]

var min = function (list) {
  return list.reduce((x, y) => {
    if (y < x) x = y;
    return x;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(min(input))
```

Comment: also [find min and max value using reduce es2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705415/find-min-and-max-value-using-reduce-es2015) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Your code is working, but in general you want to set your initial value as high as possible when looking for a `Min`, so `Infinity` in this case (if all your values were positive your current code would return 0, the initial value).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the reduce function with the first element of the array not 0.

```js
var min = function (list) {
    return list.reduce((x, y) => {
        if (y < x) x = y;
        return x;
    }, list[0]);
}

console.log(min([1, 5, 3]))
```

Comment: No you don't, you can initialize it with anything, ideally `Infinity` in this case. (Your example would return the lowest value which is < the first value of the array)

Comment: Ok, so CodeWars console mislead me, my code actually works as it is, but zero initial value here is probs not the best practice. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Initializing with the first value of the array (or any value *from the array* for that matter) guarantee that the value returned by reduce belongs to the array. With your example it wouldn't work for an array of positive integers, as your function would always return 0